# if the font color is blue then extract the date in excel

Tags: excel, vba

[image]

I need a help. I have a project where I have to extract date which is newly updated. And updated date is in blue font. So if the date is Blue Font, then I have to extract date. I wrote a vba excel code for this task. But it is not working. Can someone help me?

```
Sub color()

For n = 0 To 16
    If Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(n, 1).Font.color = RGB(0, 112, 192) Then
        Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(n, 2) = Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(n, 1)
    End If
Next

End Sub
```

[image]

Comment: There is no row `0`  your For should start at `1`

Comment: You are right. Thanks. It's working now